# Debug dockercompose service using GDB

Tags: c, linux, docker-compose, gdb, gdbserver

I am trying to Debug a service running via docker-compose through GDB.
I have the below docker-compose having two services and i wasnt to debug the 'service_test' service using gdb. iam exposing the port 5000 for the same.

[image]

I am starting the docker-compose by using the below command. 'start.sh' file is having the 'docker-compose up' command.

```
gdbserver localhost:5000 start.sh
```

in another terminal iam connecting using the below command which starts the gdb prompt terminal,

```
gdb service_exec
```

In GDB prompt terminal iam trying to connect to the target host using below commands.

```
target remote localhost:5000
continue
```

Although it executes the target program it is not able to trace the errors from the host.
The GDB prompt is stuck in the below attached message, and in gdbserver the program have ran with the error.

[image]

Any idea what could be this issue and how to resolve this?

I tried the below set commands which Andrew commented, but it does not seems to be working.  on adding the below two set commands the program is not getting executed in gdbserver terminal and the hiost terminal is showing the below log in the link.

```
set follow-fork-mode child
set detach-on-fork off
```

[gdb host log](https://www.temporary-url.com/C031)

Comment: I'm guessing the service forks a child process to actually run the service while the parent just waits for the child.  You could try `set follow-fork-mode child` and `set detach-on-fork off` in GDB before you `continue`, that might help.

Comment: Hi @Andrew ,
I tried those commands and have updated the question with the results.
gdb host log is added here : https://www.temporary-url.com/C031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug the `service_test` service with `gdb`, you should make sure the service is started with `gdbserver`. You are trying to start `gdbserver` with `start.sh`, which likely starts the entire `docker-compose` setup, rather than just the `service_test` service with `gdbserver`.

Try instead a command like this in your `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
command: gdbserver localhost:5000 /usr/local/bin/service_exec --name crash --logger 1
```

Run `docker-compose up` normally without `start.sh`. That should start the `redis` service and the `service_test` service with `gdbserver` listening on port 5000 (as described in "[How to Debug Programs on Remote Server using GDBServer Example](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/04/gdbserver-example/)", by [Lakshmanan Ganapathy](https://www.linkedin.com/in/lakshmanan-ganapathy)).

Connect to the `gdbserver` from your `gdb` client using the command you specified:

```bash
gdb service_exec
target remote localhost:5000
continue
```

Note: Make sure your `service_exec` binary is compiled with debug symbols (`-g` flag if you are using `gcc`).

```bash
Host Machine                                  Docker Container
+------------------+                          +------------------------+
| gdb service_exec |                          | service_test           |
| target remote    |     (Port 5000)          | gdbserver :5000 <cmd>  |
| localhost:5000   |------------------------->|                        |
+------------------+                          +------------------------+
```

If the issue persists after these adjustments, it might be related to the fork behavior of your service. The commands [`set follow-fork-mode child` and `set detach-on-fork off`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_25.html) in `gdb` are intended to keep `gdb` attached to the child process after a fork. If the service is designed to fork off a child process, and you want to debug the child, these settings are necessary.

---

> What if we are trying to debug a source object file? I tried the way you mentioned, and can get the error like '`Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction`'.
> But the trace back to the actual code is not available. On running the '`bt`' command, it shows '`??`' and '`__dso_handle ()`'. No trace back to the code source is showing.
> Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

When you encounter a `SIGILL, Illegal instruction` error and are unable to trace back to the source code with the `bt` (backtrace) command in GDB, it typically indicates that the debugging information is missing or incomplete. The presence of `??` and generic function names like `__dso_handle ()` usually means that GDB cannot find the source code or the debugging symbols are not available. Here are some steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

Make sure your source code is compiled with debug symbols (the `-g` flag): `gcc -g -o service_exec source_file.c`.
Be aware that compiling with optimization (e.g., `-O2` or `-O3`) can sometimes make debugging more difficult because the relationship between source code and generated code is less clear. If possible, compile with `-O0` to disable optimizations when debugging.

Make sure that you are running `gdb` on the same binary that is running inside the Docker container, not just a local copy that might be different due to recompilation or different build parameters.
If your application is using shared libraries, they also need to be compiled with debug symbols. If a shared library is missing debug symbols, GDB will not be able to provide information about the code executed within it.

Verify that the source files on your host machine match exactly with the ones used to build the binary inside the Docker container. Any mismatch can cause the debugger to show incorrect information.
GDB needs correct paths to the source files. If the binary was compiled in a different environment (e.g., inside the Docker container), the source paths embedded in the binary might not match the paths on your host system where you are running GDB. Use the `dir` command in GDB to add search directories for source files: `(gdb) dir /path/to/source/files`.

Comment: what if the we are trying to debug a source object file? I tried the way you mentioned and i am abe to get the error like 'Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction'.
but the trace back to actual code is not available. on running the 'bt' command it shows '??' and '__dso_handle ()'. no trace back to the code source is showing. any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Anvi OK, I have edited the answer to include some troubleshooting steps.